# Change of Variables in Cauchy-Euler equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm working on the change of variables in the [Cauchy-Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). And I understand everything except one step. It's the same one step skipped in the answer to the very related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307819/a-change-of-variables-in-the-euler-equation). I can get the correct answer if I do it one way but not the correct answer if I do it the other way. This is basically asking why the second method is wrong. We use the variable substitution $t=\ln(x)$ and $y(x)=\phi(t)$. (Just gonna use the notation in the wiki article to be consistent). We first know that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{x}$$

I understand that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Now I do the following:

$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\phi}{\mathrm{d}x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)=\frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\phi}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\right]-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\phi}{\mathrm{d}t^2}-\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)+\frac{1}{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align}$$

This is the correct solution with the exception of the last term. Which basically boils down to showing

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$

---

Everything above here is really just background. I have the relationship $t=\ln(x)$ and want to find $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

So I substitute in what I know is equivalent to $1/x$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(1\right)=0$$

Good. But we also know that $x=e^t$ and so instead we could just substitute

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(e^{-t}\right)=-e^{-t}=\frac{-1}{x}\ne 0$$

Why is this second method incorrect? It's got to be something so simple that I'm missing. Someone pointed out they both might be incorrect, too. It's very possible.