# differential equation Cauchy-Euler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The DE

$$ax^{2}{y}''+bx{y}'+cy=0 , x>0$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants, is called a Cauchy-Euler equation.

a) Show that the change of variable $e^{t}$ leads to:

$(D=d/dt)$

$x{y}'=Dy$

$x^{2}{y}''=D(D-1)y$

b)Using the result of part a) ,show that the Cauchy-Euler equation can be transformed into the constant-coefficient equation:

$$(aD^{2}+(b-a)D+c)y=0$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A change of variables in the euler equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307819/a-change-of-variables-in-the-euler-equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example for $y'$ we have that $x=e^t, t=\ln x$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
y'=&\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{dt}\frac {dt}{dx}\\
y'=&\frac {dy}{dt}\frac {d \ln x}{dx} \\
y'=&\frac {dy}{dt} \frac 1 x \\
\implies xy'=&\frac {dy}{dt}=Dy \\
\end{align}
$$
Do the same for $y''$:
$$
\begin{align}
y''=&\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac {d}{dx}\left (\frac {dy}{dx} \right )\\
y''=&\frac {d}{dx}\left ( \frac {dy}{dt} \frac 1 x  \right ) \\
y''=&\left (-\frac 1 {x^2} \frac {dy}{dt}   \right )+ \frac 1 x \frac {d^2y}{dt^2}\left ( \frac {dt}{dx}  \right ) \\
y''=&\left (-\frac 1 {x^2} \frac {dy}{dt}   \right )+ \frac 1 {x^2} \frac {d^2y}{dt^2} \\
\implies x^2y''=&-\frac {dy}{dt}   + \frac {d^2y}{dt^2} =D(D-1)y\\
\end{align}
$$